# No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado "file:///D:\...\bin\stdole.dll" ni una de sus dependencias. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2019

*Estoy revisando un proyecto asp.net con .Net Framework 4.0 y visual studio 2019, tengo el siguiente error:*

No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///D:...\bin\stdole.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. Error de comprobación en la signatura del nombre seguro. Puede que se manipulara el archivo o que se firmara con firma retardada, pero no con la clave privada correcta. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131045)

**Imagen del error:**

[image: Error de comprobación de signatura del nombre seguro]

Answer (score 0):

solucionado,

1. en vs 2019 ir al menú: Herramientas/Opciones
2. luego en la ventana "Opciones" ir a: Proyectos y soluciones/Proyectos web
3. ahora activar la casilla: **Usar la versión de 64 bits de IIS Express para proyectos y sitios web**
4. Aceptar

***Imagen para mejor claridad:***

[image: Usar la versión de 64 bits de IIS Express para proyectos y sitios web]